# Combine data with different shapes for tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have been searching for the best way to do this for a week now, and I am giving up.

I am trying to build a tensorflow model that learns from three different features for each input. The issue is that the features have different shapes.

E.g.:

```
elem0 = {'feat0':[1,3,5],'feat1':[1,2],'feat2':[[0,1],[1,1]]}
elem1 = {'feat0':[0,5,1],'feat1':[2,9],'feat2':[[0,0],[1,0]]}
elem2 = {'feat0':[5,3,7],'feat1':[3,6],'feat2':[[1,1],[1,0]]}
```

The best I could do was to create three "columns" in tf, as follows:

```
x0 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = (None, 3), name = 'feat0')
x1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = (None, 2), name = 'feat1')
x2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = (None, 2, 2), name = 'feat2')

y0 = tf.layers.dense(x0, units = 1)
y1 = tf.layers.dense(x1, units = 1)
y2 = tf.layers.dense(x2, units = 1)

y_concat = tf.concat([y0,y1,y2],1)

y = tf.layers.dense(y_concat, units = 1)
```

The "issue" with that is that I have no idea if I should, and if so, how, use the new `Dataset` class in tensorflow.

As of now, I can run my model with

```
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
res = sess.run(y, {x0:[elem0[feat0],elem1[feat0],elem2[feat0]],
                   x1:[elem0[feat1],elem1[feat1],elem2[feat1]], 
                   x2:[elem0[feat2],elem1[feat2],elem2[feat2]]
})
```

What I would really like is having the chance to create a dataset iterator over my elements, returning the three "columns" of data.

Something like:

```
def generate_tensor_set():
    <some code, maybe getting my inputs from a SQL db>
    return x0_batch, x1_batch, x2_batch
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After writing this, I went and read a few tutorials about the new API.

I managed to solve, hopefully in the "right" TF way.

The new `Dataset` API allowed me to do this.

All my tensors come from a generator. This generator returns 3 numpy arrays and a label for each instance of the input data.

E.g.:

```
def generate_tensor_set(arg_example):
    <get the data in some way, maybe using arg_example>
    return x0, x1, x2, y
```

From the generator I created an input function that uses a dataset created from the generator. The `lambda` is used to pass parameters to the generator in  `from_generator`

```
def my_input_fn(batch_size):
    ds = tf.data.Dataset().from_generator(lambda:generate_tensor_set(arg_example=an_arg),
        output_types = (tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.int32)
        output_shapes = (tf.Tensorshape([3]),
                         tf.Tensorshape([2]),
                         tf.Tensorshape([2,2])))
    ds.batch(batch_size)
    x0, x1, x2, label = ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
    return {"x0": x0, "x1": x1, "x2": x2}, label
```

The `tf.int32` in the input function is just because I used `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy` which wants an `int32` as input for labels (I guess, using that solved my issues).

Then a model function:

```
def model_function(features, labels, mode, params):
    y0 = tf.layers.dense(features['x0'], units = 1)
    y1 = tf.layers.dense(features['x1'], units = 1)
    y2 = tf.layers.dense(features['x2'], units = 1)
    y_concat = tf.concat([y0,y1,y2],1)
    y = tf.layers.dense(y_concat, units = 1)
    logits = tf.layers.dense(y_concat, units = 2)

    <loss, train_op, a bunch of other stuff>
```

The `bunch of other stuff` is decently described in the [custom estimator documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/custom_estimators)

Then,

```
my_feature_columns = [  tf.feature_column.numeric_column("x0", shape=(3), dtype=tf.float32),
                        tf.feature_column.numeric_column("x1", shape=(2), dtype=tf.float32),
                        tf.feature_column.numeric_column("x2", shape=(2,2), dtype=tf.float32)]

classifier_mymodel = tf.estimator.Estimator(
    model_fn = model_function,
    params = {'feature_columns': my_feature_columns})

classifier_mymodel.train(input_fn = lambda: my_input_fn(batch_size = 16)
```